# i keep getting a compiler error saying, Rainfallmain.java:13: error: <identifier> expected.

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not sure why, the compiler error points at the string Array. should i make a for loop and manually  fill each subscript with a name of the months for the year? please help!!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rainfallmain
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    double months = 12;
  double average = Rainfallyr.getAverage();
  double Mostrain = Rainfallyr.getHighest();
  double Leastrain = Rainfallyr.getLowest();
  double total = Rainfallyr.getTotal();
    double [] Rainfallyr =  new Rainfall[months];
  String[] Mon = {"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August". "September", "October", "November", "December"};

     getRainvalues(Rainfallyr, mon);

  System.out.println(" The total rainfall for the year is "  + Mostrain);
  System.out.println(" The total least aount of rain is "  + Leastrain);
  System.out.println(" The total rainfall for the year is "  + total);
  System.out.println(" The average rainfall for the year is "  + average);


}


}
    public static void getAllvalues(double []rain, String [] mon)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
      {
        System.out.print(" Enter Rain for each month" +mon[i]+" :");
        r[i] = input.nextDouble();


      }




    }
```

Comment: What environment are you coding in that it didn't point out that period?

Comment: could you recommend me an IDE that isnt hard to use for a inexperienced programmer?

Answer (score 2):

```
"August". "September"
```

The member-access operator `.` needs to be followed by an identifier (the name of the member being accessed), not a string literal. That's why the error message says "identifier expected".

You probably meant to use a comma there.